# BASH: AWK pivot CSV into desired table

Tags: text-processing, awk, table

I have been struggling with pivoting .csv file into desired table format using bash.

My file o/p:

```
$ cat finalcount.csv
state,status,count
NW,CONGESTED,11
NW,CLEARED,9
ACT,CLEARED,7
ACT,CONGESTED,7
QLD,CLEARED,5
WA,CONGESTED,3
WA,CLEARED,2
VIC,CLEARED,3
VIC,CONGESTED,2
```

My desired o/p:

```
State   Congested  Cleared
ACT     7          7
NW      11         9
VIC     2          3
QLD     -          5
```

Please share your answer with explanation.

Comment: please, explain the transfomation

Comment: If an answer worked for you then see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html):

```
$ mlr --icsvlite --opprint \
    reshape -s status,count then unsparsify then reorder -e -f CLEARED finalcount.csv
state CONGESTED CLEARED
NW    11        9
ACT   7         7
QLD   -         5
WA    3         2
VIC   2         3
```

---

[GNU Datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) is also handy for things like pivot tables (aka cross-tabulation) although there doesn't appear to be any easy way to control column order:

```
datamash --header-in --filler=- -t, crosstab 1,2 unique 3 < finalcount.csv | csvformat -T
         CLEARED  CONGESTED
ACT      7          7
NW       9          11
QLD      5          -
VIC      3          2
WA       2          3
```

---

If you really need to use Awk, then something like this should work:

```
awk -F, '
  NR>1 {s[$1]} 
  $2 == "CONGESTED" {a[$1]=$3} 
  $2 == "CLEARED" {b[$1]=$3} 
  END {
    printf "state\tcongested\tcleared\n"; 
    for (k in s) 
      printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", k, a[k]=="" ? "-" : a[k], b[k]=="" ? "-" : b[k]      
  }
' finalcount.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
{ sub(/\r$/,"") }
NR > 1 {
    states[$1]
    statuses[$2]
    vals[$1,$2] = $NF
}
END {
    printf "%s", "state"
    for (status in statuses) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, status
    }
    print ""

    for (state in states) {
        printf "%s", state
        for (status in statuses) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, ((state,status) in vals ? vals[state,status] : "-")
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
state   CONGESTED       CLEARED
QLD     -       5
ACT     7       7
WA      3       2
NW      11      9
VIC     2       3
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s $'\t' -t
state  CONGESTED  CLEARED
QLD    -          5
ACT    7          7
WA     3          2
NW     11         9
VIC    2          3
```

Comment: could pls elaborate the commands that are being executed in AWK..I'm a newbie into bash scripting

Comment: bash scripting has nothing to do with awk scripting. bash and awk are 2 completely different tools. You can call awk from bash (and you can call bash from awk) but you can also call awk from any other UNIX shell or from Windows and you can call many other tools from bash (sed, grep, perl, etc.). I won't be able to teach you the fundamentals of awk scripting in this comment so please take a look at the man page and google some examples, add some `print` statements to the script to see which values/variables are being used, and then let me know if you have any specific questions.

Comment: wow! it works for not just two, but more multiple rows to columns conversion. A very interesting script. Can you add another feature to it. There is a ^M character comes in. How can we avoid it?

Comment: I added a sub() at the top to remove the ^Ms you get from DOS line endings as I assume that's what you're referring to. See [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more information on that.

Comment: @EdMorton that worked for me, your other answer is also informative. I had one more thing to ask you and since it's related to vim, I have asked it as a new question, here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28699/how-can-i-run-awk-script-with-in-vim

Comment: I wouldn't be able to help you with any vim question, I just use it for the simple stuff that no-one could have to ask questions about.

Comment: Well, thank you very much. The vim question I posted turns out to be very basic one. And hope you don't mind.

Comment: It's doing something I've never considered doing while in an editor session in 40 years of using vi and vim so it's not basic to me and I don't have any input on it, sorry.